# Cannot query field 'password' on type 'User' graphql

Tags: graphql, schema, react-apollo, prisma

I'm using graphql and prisma.

**datamodel.prisma**

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  first_name: String
}
```

**schema.graphql**

```
scalar Date

type Query {
  users: [User!]!
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  createdAt: Date!
  updatedAt: Date!
  email: String!
  first_name: String
}
```

**resolver**

```
users: (parent, args, context) => {
  return context.prisma.users();
}
```

I expected to get a user list, but received the error:
**query**

```
{
  users {
    email
  }
}
```

**error**

`"Cannot query field 'password' on type 'User'. (line 7, column 5):\n    password\n    ^"`

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
Tried to use a fragment, but got the same:

```
{
  users {
    ...userFields
  }
}

fragment userFields on User {
  email
}
```

Comment: When i removed password field - everything is working, but I need this field for user creation.

Comment: use `fragment`s

Comment: @xadm The same

`{
  users {
    ...userFields
  }
}

fragment userFields on User {
  email
}`

Comment: ... clone User type into UserInput (for mutate/creation usage ), remove password from User type

Comment: @xadm could you provide some small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created custom query which return a fragment and seems the error gone.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to also add a scenario that can very easily cause this same issue that took me a while to debug and I'm sure others will encounter, because it took me quite some time to realize the issue was actually being caused in my FRONTEND code where I was defining my auth-related Mutations.

#### Set Up

Here's what that looked like while developing much of my application:

`datamodel.prisma` (I've omitted some fields for simplicity sake)

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
}
```

`schema.graphql` (just showing the `signUp` Mutation for simplicity)

```
type Mutation {
  signUp(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): User!
}
```

`SignUp.js` (where I access the `signUp` Mutation exposed in `schema.graphql`)

```
const SIGNUP_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation SIGNUP_MUTATION(
    $email: String!
    $name: String!
    $password: String!
  ) {
    signUp(email: $email, name: $name, password: $password) {
      id
      email
      name
      password
    }
  }
`
```

Notice that I am returning `id`, `email`, `name`, and `password` - this was because I wanted to make sure everything was working in development.

---

#### Introducing the `Cannot query field 'password' on type 'User'` error

Once I began working on security and created a special `User` type in `schema.graphql` so that I could hide protected fields such as `password`, that's when I got this issue:

`schema.graphql` (notice that I am now not exposing the `password` field on this frontend-facing User type)

```
type Mutation {
  signUp(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): User!
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
}
```

#### Solution

Because of the nature of this error message, I spent most of my morning puzzling over my backend code. But it turned out that the error was actually being caused in `SignUp.js`, where I was RETURNING the `password` field.

The solution was to simply remove that line from the list of return fields like so:

```
const SIGNUP_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation SIGNUP_MUTATION(
    $email: String!
    $name: String!
    $password: String!
  ) {
    signUp(email: $email, name: $name, password: $password) {
      id
      email
      name
    }
  }
`
```

#### Key Lessons

1. So if you're experiencing this issue, please check ALL of your relevant mutations and make sure that you're not returning any fields that you have protected as I described here.
2. Be sure to also check your frontend code and make sure you aren't trying to return fields that you have now protected and are no longer exposing to the frontend.

I hope this is helpful and saves people some time!

Answer (score 1):

... aaah Prisma ...

I don't know if interfaces, unions or input types are supported. Graphql [docs](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types)

Prisma generates almost everything ... but defining password as required (as type for DBB generation) for datamodel should not block querying for a type subset or type defined on existing model without using all fields.

For me it's a bit missleading error message. It can be resolver related.

Try to `match` types in resolver, don't return direct prisma query (operates on model types), but map queried data (an array) to filter out password field/property (to be query type compatible). It's a security concern, too - passwords shouldn't be read from outside.

Comment: Yeap, i've created custom query which return a fragment and seems the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just run in your console(in prisma folder):

```
PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=mysecret42 prisma deploy
```